# When testing CAPM why is r-squared so low?

Tags: regression, time-series, statistical-significance, r-squared, finance

I am testing CAPM, Fama-French & Carhart-models (so a 1-factor, 3-factor and 4-factor model) for financial portfolios (60 observations). There is one type of portfolio with low R²'s.

- The CAPM model shows an Adj. R² of: 0,1457
- The Fama-French model shows an Adj. R² of: 0,1260
- The Carhart model shows an Adj. R² of: 0,1731

I don't really know what is wrong with the other results. All my other porfolio's show R² of more than 70%, only this one doesn't. I am kind of stuck with this portfolio. Is there a way to increase the R²?

The CAPM model also shows the following information:

```
alpha coefficient: 0,0081 ; t-stat 1,2578 ; Prob. 0,2048
beta coefficient: 0,2587 ; t-stat 3,4569 ; Prob. 0,0015
Akaike info criterion -3,1785
Schwarz criterion -3,1158
Hannan-Quinn criterion -3,2015
Durbin-Watson 1,9087
S.E. of regression 0,0482
Sum squared resid 0,1458
Log likelihood 97,1254
F-statistic 11,0684
Prob(F-statistic) 0,0015
```

Comment: Do you also get not significant alphas in your other portfolios? Do the other portfolios contain the same amount of observations as this one?

Comment: The alpha's of the other portfolio's are mostly > 0,1. And they all count the same number of observations

Comment: Did you check the assumptions of the model? Are there outliers? Are there data entry errors?

Comment: For now, I checked the scatterplot (looked quite normal). The histogram doesn't really look like a perfect normal distribution and shows some skewness. Some extra info: Skewness: -0,3782. Kurtosis: 3,5792. Jarque-Bera: 2,1823. I don't really know what other fundamental tests I should run?